# Divergência entre dados de Um Array populados manual e de uma variavel

Tags: php

Não estou sabendo como tratar isso, se eu coloco os dados no array manualmente o array vem correto  se eu coloco os mesmo dados vindo de uma variavel o array já errado. como posso fazer a variável funcionar corretamente

1 Opção dados inseridos manualmente no array

```
print_r ($poligono = array("-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345", "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936"));
Resultado Correto
//Array ( [0] => -22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345 [1] => -22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936 )
```

2 Opção dados idênticos só que vindo em uma variável

```
poli = '"-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345", "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936"';
print_r ($poligono = array($poli));
Resultado Errado
//Array ( [0] => "-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345", "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936" )
```

Comment: Ola. basicamente "-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345", "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936"  funciona meu script   se coloco em  uma variavel não funciona

Comment: mais não pode ficar só na primeira posição

Comment: esse valores vem do banco , a questão é porque manualmente vai e pela variavel não

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma série de problemas no que você está fazendo.

Veja o primeiro caso:

```
$poligono = array( "-22.8919, -43.1272", "-22.8652, -43.0954" );
                   |_____valor 1______|  |_____valor 2______|
```

Você claramente está criando um array com dois elementos.

Vamos ao segundo caso:

```
$poligono = array(   $poli   );
                  |_valor 1_|
```

Da mesma forma, você está claramente criando um array com um valor só.

Veja um exemplo igual ao seu segundo caso:

```
$poligono = array( '"-22.8919, -43.1272", "-22.8652, -43.0954"' );
                   |__________________valor 1_________________|
```

Desta forma, você vai ter o mesmo resultado que o exemplo anterior. Um valor só, na posição zero.

Se quiser colocar valores em posições separadas, tem que fornecê-los separadamente:

```
$valor1 = "-22.8919, -43.1272";
$valor2 = "-22.8652, -43.0954";
$poligono = array( $valor1, $valor2 );
```

Basicamente o PHP vai fazer o que você manda ele fazer. Se manda por um valor, ele obedece. Se manda por dois, também obedece.

Quanto a isto aqui:

```
$poli = '"-22.8919, -43.1272", "-22.8652, -43.0954"';
```

Você está criando um valor só, entre aspas simples `'`. Se puser num array, vai continuar sendo um valor só. Tudo depende de onde você pega o valor, para ver o melhor jeito de dividir, ou de usar dividido.

Se realmente precisar fazer uma gambiarra, uma solução é essa:

```
$poli = '"-22.8919, -43.1272", "-22.8652, -43.0954"';
$poli = str_replace( ' ', '', $poli );
$poli = str_replace( '","', '"|"', $poli );
print_r ( $poligono = explode( '|', $poli ) );
```

E se não quiser as aspas no resultado:

```
$poli = '"-22.8919, -43.1272", "-22.8652, -43.0954"';
$poli = str_replace( ' ', '', $poli );
$poli = str_replace( '","', '"|"', $poli );
$poli = str_replace( '"', '', $poli );
print_r ( $poligono = explode( '|', $poli ) );
```

Mas não recomendo esta solução, se enxergar isso em algum código real, é mau sinal. A solução correta é pegar os valores separadamente do DB, e usar separadamente no array().

Comment: OK entendi... só nesse meu caso como poderia separar esses valores estão na variavel

Comment: po... quase agora a divisão foi muita   Array ( [0] => "-22.891996181150216 [1] => 43.127254512695345" [2] => "-22.86529776201615 [3] => -43.09548266210936" ) 
teria que ser em 2 posições

Comment: @FabioHenrique veja o resultado funcionando ->  http://ideone.com/Az5uu6

Comment: Show Obrigado por mais que seje uma gambiarra  vai quebrar meu galho momentaneamente

Answer (score 1):

No primeiro tem um array com 2 índices.

No segundo, apenas gerou um array com um índice único pois o array não será auto construído a partir de uma string como parâmetro.

Caso queria gerar um array a partir de uma string, é necessário que a string tenha um padrão para poder usar uma função como `explode()`, para facilitar a "conversão":

```
$poli = '"-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345", "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936"';

$poligono = explode('",', $poli);
print_r($poligono);
```

A lógica aqui é usar `",` como delimitador. Assim, a função `explode()` gerará um array com 2 índices ou a quantidade delimitadores que encontrar.

Mas ainda assim terá um resultado estranho

```
Array
(
    [0] => "-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345
    [1] =>  "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936"
)
```

Note as aspas duplas.

Um exemplo mais consistente para gerar o array:

```
$poli = '"-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345", "-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936"';
$poli = explode(', ', str_replace('"', '', $poli));
$poligono = array(
    $poli[0].' '.$poli[1],
    $poli[2].' '.$poli[3]
);
print_r($poligono);


/*
retorna

Array
(
    [0] => -22.891996181150216 -43.127254512695345
    [1] => -22.86529776201615 -43.09548266210936
)
*/
```

Enfim, isso depende de como a string original é recebida na variável `$poli`. Pois se vier algo fora do padrão, terá erro em algum processo. Se realmente tiver certeza de que a string possuirá o mesmo formato, a rotina funcionará, se não, terá que criar algo mais consistente.